# javascript change json array to another json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a web service returns this data

```
[
  {
    "Campaign": "default",
    "TotalInBound": 216.0
  },
  {
    "Campaign": "direct",
    "TotalInBound": 10.0
  },
  {
    "Campaign": "Sales",
    "TotalInBound": 151.0
  },
  {
    "Campaign": "Support",
    "TotalInBound": 2.0
  }
]
```

I am using a jquery library which its input is like this:

```
data = [
        { label: "Product 1", data: Math.floor (Math.random() * 100 + 250) }, 
        { label: "Product 2", data: Math.floor (Math.random() * 100 + 350) }, 
        { label: "Product 3", data: Math.floor (Math.random() * 100 + 650) }, 
        { label: "Product 4", data: Math.floor (Math.random() * 100 + 50) },
        { label: "Product 5", data: Math.floor (Math.random() * 100 + 250) }
    ];
```

I want to change my data to that form of data . for example, **the final result will be like this:**

```
data = [
{label:"default", data:216.0},
{label:"direct", data:10.0 },
...
...
];
```

could you help please. i tried to use loops many times, but nothing works.

Comment: Please share with us your attempts so that we can identify the problem and suggest some solutions.

Comment: @Lix actually I tried to make a loop on the first json. then I didn't know how to contact the loop with the new json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ehh, like so:

```
var newData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < currentData.length; i++) {
    var obj = {}
    obj.label = currentData[i].Campaign;
    obj.data = currentData[i].TotalInBound;
    newData.push(obj);
}
```

`newData` will now be an array in the correct format.

Comment: +1 I will accpet your answer after 8 minutes. thanks a lot . you great